# Which function should I choose?

Tags: functions

I am writing a paper and looking for a function.Its shape is just like this:[image]

when its x value is very small ,its y is close to 0 , but when x value is a little big, then its y value is very close to 1.

Anyone can tell me ?

Comment: $\tanh x$ ([hyperbolic tangent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicTangent.html)) and $\operatorname{erf} x$ ([error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html)) both have shapes like this.

Comment: What paper is it about? Why are you looking for such function?

Answer (score 1):

function = Amplitude(1 - Exp[-x/(constant)])

Keep amplitude=1 and adjust constant as per ur need

Look at growth function such as in RC circuit